# Umbraco hostname cannot be set

Tags: iis, umbraco, umbraco7

When I attempt to set a hostname on my site, I am getting the error message

```
"Authorisation has been denied for this request"
```

I'm logged in as an Administrator and cannot work out what it is that I am not authorised to do. The hostname is perfectly valid that I am entering

Is it Umbraco refusing the request or IIS?

Comment: Are you getting this error message in IIS or in the umbraco backend?

Comment: @Mark - the message is in the Umbraco backend when I attempt to save the Cultures and Hostnames page

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the user you are logged in as does not have permission to set the host names for the site. It's a permission that's set in the user types in the users section.

Got to the Users section in the back office, expand "user types", choose the type that your user is set to, and ensure that "Culture and Hostnames" is checked in the default permissions tree.

If you can't see the permission there to check it, it means you need to get someone with full Administrator access to set it for you, and then log out and log back in again.